# Panning in React Three Fiber

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

When I right click, I can move my camera up and down. By default, when my model loads, half of its body is out of the frame. I want to move the camera down, so the whole body fits in the frame. Is there a setting to do this? I’ve tried using camera position but that didn’t work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

when I come across cases like this I do this:

1. try to scale down the object first, so that I can see the whole picture
2. add [axesHelpers](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/helpers/AxesHelper) to object or scene, to figure out which direction should I move to
3. change position of camera accordingly.